# Laravel soft delete en tablas pivote

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pivot, relaciones

Tengo una relación `m-n` entre dos tablas mediante una tabla pivote. En la migration de la tabla pivote la he creado con un campo `deleted_at`, mediante el método `softDeletes()`, así:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('customer_store', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        /** Satisfacción */
        $table->char('satisfaccion', 1)->nullable();
        /** Los campos de fechas */
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        /** La definición de los campos que se usarán como claves foráneas */
        $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('store_id')->unsigned();
        /** La declaración de las claves foráneas en los campos necesarios. */
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
        $table->foreign('store_id')->references('id')->on('stores');
    });
}
```

Además, como se ve, también he añadido un campo llamado `satisfaccion`. El objetivo es que la misma relación incluya datos que son inherentes a esa relación.

La cuestión es que cuando se desasocian los elementos (los clientes y las tiendas), no quiero que se borre la relación, ya que esta debe permanecer a modo de histórico, por cuestiones de trazabilidad. Sin embargo, el método `detach()` no mira que haya o no un campo `deleted_at`. Elimina la relación por las buenas.
Hay algún método específico para que las relaciones se marquen en el campo `deleted_at`, o habría de programarlo manualmente usando el modelo de la tabla pivote?

Y luego lo más importante. A la hora de obtener una lista de los clientes relacionados con una tienda, como puedo decidir si quiero ver todas las relaciones, o sólo las que estén activas (que tengan `null` en `deleted_at`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las tablas pivote en Laravel (y en la bases de datos en general) no son más que la representación de relaciones, y no tienen una llave primaria (o al menos no deberían tenerla), porque si la tuvieran, serían un modelo y tendrían «vida propia», como los demás modelos.

Al ser totalmente dependientes de los modelos, no pueden tener las mismas funcionalidades y/o características de estos, y en Laravel está bien sustentado, en este caso no habría una forma «correcta» de hallar la relación.

En términos de código lo encontramos en el trait de SoftDeletes, donde se observa que se necesita una llave primaria para realizar el soft delete, por ende una instancia del modelo:

```
/**
 * Perform the actual delete query on this model instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function runSoftDelete()
{
    $query = $this->newModelQuery()->where($this->getKeyName(), $this->getKey());

    $time = $this->freshTimestamp();

    $columns = [$this->getDeletedAtColumn() => $this->fromDateTime($time)];

    $this->{$this->getDeletedAtColumn()} = $time;

    if ($this->timestamps && ! is_null($this->getUpdatedAtColumn())) {
        $this->{$this->getUpdatedAtColumn()} = $time;

        $columns[$this->getUpdatedAtColumn()] = $this->fromDateTime($time);
    }

    $query->update($columns);
}
```

---

Hay muchas soluciones planteadas para esto, desde jugar a agregar el trait softdeletes en ciertas partes para pretender usar los métodos de Laravel, hasta paquetes desarrollados exclusivamente con este fin.

En mi opinión, una de las soluciones más interesantes es la de aprovechar el eager load con este fin al definir la relación:

```
public function stores()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Store')
        ->whereNull('customer_store.deleted_at')
        ->withTimestamps();

}
```

El soft delete se realizaría así:

```
DB::table('customer_store')
->where('customer_id', $customer_id)
->where('store_id', $srote_id)
->update(['deleted_at' => now()]);
```

Y en cuanto a la segunda respuesta, la solución también fue planteada de forma implícita arriba, aunque se puede hacer de otras formas también.

Comment: Suena bien, pero me marca error al crear un nuevo registro y su nueva relación: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; ` Y curiosamente sí se guardan todos los registros ...

Comment: @Pathros el error probablemente sea bastante explícito.

Comment: Ya. Sí funciona. Estaba borrando los registros en la tabla relacional porque arriba tenía el `$store->find($id)->customers()->detach();`. Pero qué mal que tengamos que hacer este mega `workaround`. Ojalá Laravel incluya pronto `SoftDeletes`para las tablas pivote de manera más simplificada.

Answer (score 0):

Tras hacer varias pruebas, y googlear unas cuantas horas, veo que las tablas pivote son, exactamente, eso: bisagras entre dos o más claves foráneas. Datos adicionales deben ser almacenados en otras tablas diseñadas al efecto, no en las tablas pivote.
Me ha costado, pero he entendido que mi planteamiento era erróneo, y que limita las prestaciones de Laravel y de Eloquent, haciendo que algunos métodos no funcionen como esperaba.
Una vez separado el contenido en los modelos necesarios, todo funciona a pedir de boca, siguiendo la documentación y los manuales que hay.
Pongo estos comentarios para que si algún otro novato en Laravel (como yo mismo) tiene la misma idea, que sepa que no, que las tablas pivote no son el ungüento amarillo.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta sino un comentario extendido, cuando publiques respuestas al redactar se objetivo

Comment: Es decir tu planteaste al final de tu pub. Unas preguntas dime cómo se resolvieron ?

Comment: Hola, Shadow. Como siempre, agradezco tus comentarios, que ayudan a mejorar la comunidad. En la auto respuesta que puse, intenté ser concluyente. Te ruego que me disculpes si no he sabido darle la forma correcta. La solución a mi planteamiento inicial pasa por montar otro modelo, de una tabla de datos (no pivote). Aún estoy puliéndolo, pero el concepto lo tengo claro. Gracias también a Shaz, que siempre va un paso más allá, exprimiendo al máximo los recursos de la herramienta.

Comment: @Chefito O haz lo que yo: copia el texto de esta respuesta, pégala al final de tu pregunta y luego borra esta respuesta. Posteriormente, yo borraré este comentario.